# Exit shell script from python

Tags: python, shell

I Have a shell script which in turn runs a python script, I have to exit from the main shell script when an exception is caught in python. Can anyone suggest a way on how to achieve it.

Comment: Check the exit status after running your script (in `bash` that will be `$?`)

Comment: Is the exception *caught* (and handled) in Python, or does the Python script exit when the exception is raised?

Comment: python script is exited and the control returns to shell, I want the shell script to be terminated at that point of time.

Comment: use **return** to exit from main shell script

Comment: Or `set -e` in the bash script, to immediately terminate if any of the commands it runs returns a non-zero exit status. It's a good safety tip for bash scripts

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can set the return value using `sys.exit()`. Typically when execution completed successfully you return 0, and if not then some non-zero number.

So something like this in your Python will work:

```
import sys

try:
    ....
except:
    sys.exit(1)
```

And then, as others have said, you need to make sure your bash script catches the error by either checking the return value explicitly (using e.g. `$?`) or using `set -e`.